# How do you load the Viewbag with only items that are set to "Available"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my program with the following model:

```
public class PlayToy {
    public int PlayToyID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool Available {get;set;}
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
Viewbag.PlayToyID = new SelectList(db.PlayToys, "PlayToyID", "Name");
```

Here is the View

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlayToy
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("PlayToyID", "Choose a Toy")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayToyID)
</div>
```

This works fine for showing dropdown list of all the Toys on the list, but I would like 
to only show the the Items that are 'Available' to play with.

I am new to MVC, so I don't know AJAX or any other Scripting languages to integrate into MVC. So I was wondering how to do this with using just MVC, and would the code to filter the list go in the controller or the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ to filter your list using the `Where()` operator

```
Viewbag.PlayToyID = newSelectList(db.PlayToys.Where(x=>x.Available).ToList(), "PlayToyID", "Name");
```

I recommend reading up a little on LINQ and how you can apply it to Lists and use in things like Entity Framework.  It is an extremely powerful tool in the .NET toolkit for filtering, ordering, grouping, sorting, etc.